# String Arrays in Guvnor rule

Tags: arrays, drools, drools-guvnor

I am having some difficulty in understanding how a String[] can be represented in a Guvnor rule. How can an array of strings be passed to a Java method that uses String[] as an argument from a rule in Guvnor?

I keep getting mismatched input errors, Error Code 102 when I attempt to validate the rule in Guvnor.

Any pointers/tips welcome

In the following rule, comm is a global object with a function sendMail with the function signature (String[] recipientlist, String alertType, String message)

```
rule "list-email"
    dialect "java"
        when
            $result : Grade( subject == "Math" , $marks : mark >= 99.0 )
            $emailList : "{xyz@abc.com, fgh@def.com}"
        then
            comm.sendMail($emailList, "High Grade Alert", "Scored: " + " Marks:" +       Double.toString($marks));
```

Comment: I think you had better explain where your $emailList is coming from. At least in your example code, it's a String rather than an array of String. You may also find it easier to work with collections rather than arrays, as that is what Drools will naturally collect.

Comment: $emailList is a variable on the LHS, probably not a good idea as pointed by @laune. Can you give more details to as how collections can be used in a rule - with the flexibility for business users to add/remove to/from the collections. The business user has no notion of what a Java collection or array is - they only see the emailList as a "box" or placeholder to hold the email addresses.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to try and introduce a String[] on the LHS - you aren't *matching* with it, and I doubt the syntax is correct. Use this - on the RHS it's Java:

```
rule "list-email"
dialect "java"
when
    $result : Grade( subject == "Math" , $marks : mark >= 99.0 )
then
    String[] addrs = new String[]{"xyz@abc.com", "fgh@def.com"};
    comm.sendMail(addrs, "High Grade Alert", "Scored: " + " Marks:" + $marks );
end
```

Comment: Can this be done without using Java? I have business users that are not proficient in Java - so as much as possible I want to avoid using Java in the rules. All in all, just need the users to be able to have the flexibility to add email addresses.

Comment: I'd say that providing a set of email addresses that should be used when subject is Math and the mark >= 99 is a *data item* or *fact* that has to be provided in a way convenient to your users. If there are several other such combinations (Music, mark >= 90; English, mark >= 94; etc.) you'll have a fact defining such a triple: subject, mark, addresses. Also, it's possible that a decision table fits this scenario, where users enter data in a MS Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, the set of email addresses is not a data item or fact. Rather, it is part of the consequence - The data item combinations can lead to an email being sent or not. Decision tables in Excel are a bit unwieldy, would like to avoid using decision tables.

Comment: Quite so - but there are numerous cases where the combination of (a,b,c) of literals in a rule was better put into a "parameter fact", saving you the bother of writing umpteen rules, with a single rule matching a and b against "regular" facts and providing c for the reactive consequence. - When you write a rule like your "list-email", isn't it a *fact* that you combine Math, 99% and those two emails...?